# moment of inertia when a shape is cut

Tags: homework-and-exercises, moment-of-inertia

A disk of radius $r_1$ is cut from a disk of radius $r_2$, $(r_2>r_1)$ from the middle of the bigger disk . If the annular ring left has mass $M$ then find the moment of inertia about the axis passing through its centre and perpendicular to its plane.

Comment: Hi and welcome to the Physics SE! Please note that this is not a homework help site. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093/should-any-check-my-work-questions-be-made-on-topic).

Comment: I edited the question to clarify what you meant, if it doesn't reflect what you were asking, feel free to change it. And which part has mass $M$? The remaining ring or the cut out (smaller) disc? Please be more specific.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose your disk has uniform density. Then the mass of the whole disk is

$$M\frac{\pi r_2^2}{\pi (r_2^2-r_1^2)}=M\frac{r_2^2}{r_2^2-r_1^2}$$

and the mass of the smaller disk is

$$M\frac{\pi r_1^2}{\pi (r_2^2-r_1^2)}=M\frac{r_1^2}{r_2^2-r_1^2}$$

The momentum of inertia of the whole disk is

$$\frac{1}{2}M\frac{r_2^2}{r_2^2-r_1^2}r_2^2$$

The moment of inertia of the smaller disk is

$$\frac{1}{2}M\frac{r_1^2}{r_2^2-r_1^2}r_1^2$$

Hence the momentum of inertia of the ring is

$$\frac{1}{2}M\frac{r_2^2}{r_2^2-r_1^2}r_2^2-\frac{1}{2}M\frac{r_1^2}{r_2^2-r_1^2}r_1^2=\frac{1}{2}M\frac{r_2^4-r_1^4}{r_2^2-r_1^2}=\frac{1}{2}M(r_1^2+r_2^2)$$

Comment: I think the OP is referring to the mass of _smaller_ disk as mass $M$

Comment: But he said the disk "left". I therefore think he is referring to the "ring" left.

Comment: @Kyson I think too, if he was referring to the smaller disc as $M$, and wanted its moment of inertia, I think the question would be too trivial.

Comment: Probably, but the question is very badly posted.

Answer (score 1):

Without working out all the details of the answer for you, the basic concept is that 
$$I_{total-axis-1} = \sum_j \left(I_{j-axis-1} \right).$$
That is, the moment of inertia of an extended object about a certain axis (e.g., axis-1) is the sum of moments of inertia of pieces of that object about the same axis.  If you want to subdivide a large object into two smaller pieces, this concept holds true.

You must be *careful* to use the proper masses, positions (radii) when calculating each moment, but the principle of sums will be you started.

Answer (score 0):

A solid disk has mass $m = \rho z\pi r^2$. The total mass of annular ring is found from adding uniform density disk of $r_2$ and subtracting a disk of $r_1$

$$ \left. M = \rho z \pi (r_2^2-r_1^2) \right\} \rho = \frac{M}{z \pi (r_2^2-r_1^2)} $$

The mass moment of inertia of solid disk is $I=\frac{m}{2} r^2 = \frac{1}{2} \rho \pi z r^4$

The total mass moment of inertia is found from adding a uniform disk of $r_2$ and subtracting a disk of $r_1$

$$ I = \frac{1}{2} \rho \pi z (r_2^4-r_1^4) $$

Using the density from above this becomes

$$ I = \frac{m}{2} \frac{ r_2^4-r_1^4}{r_2^2-r_1^2} = \frac{m}{2} \left( r_1^2+r_2^2 \right) $$

Answer (score -1):

Moment of inertia of disc is *(I=mr^2)/2* now what you are saying is this that it is cut from another disc so it is still a disc.so you can put the value of radius in above equation to get answer.

Comment: It is not `still a disc`, it is an annular ring.

Comment: @AritraDas The question is not clear, nothing wrong with this interpretation of the question either.

Comment: @TheGhostOfPerdition I think the OP misused the term `disc` for annular ring, otherwise the question would be too trivial.