# Moment of inertia of a disk with a hole

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, moment-of-inertia

[image]

I was trying to find the moment of inertia of the disk object the following way

$$I_o = I_d-I_h$$ where $$I_0$$ is the moment of inertia of the disk with a hole and $$I_d$$ is the moment of inertia of the disk without a hole and $$I_h$$ is the moment of inertia of the hole

then to find $$I_h$$ I use the parallel axis theorem such that
$$I_h = I_{cm} + md^2$$
is there any other way to calculate the moment of inertia of the hole? because the problem with finding the moment of inertia of the hole with the parallel axis theorem is that the hole does not intersect with the center of the disk

Comment: There is no problem with the hole not intersecting the disk center, the parallel axis theorem is still true. The net I is the I of the solid disk minus the I of the hole, and the I of the hole is the I of a disk of the radius of the hole minus plus the hole area times the offset from the large disk center.

Comment: Ramanujans, if the question is for the I about the center of the large disk, the formula you posted is correct. The correct d to use is the distance between the two centers.

Comment: can you elaborate in the finding of the I of the hole please

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/227913/392

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I for the solid disk is found with the

$$
I_{d} = \frac{1}{2}MR^{2}
$$

equation. The same equation is used for the $I_{cm}$ of the hole:

$$
I_{cm} = \frac{1}{2}mr^{2}
$$

The offset used is $md^{2}$, where I assume $d$ is given.

The $M$ and $m$ will come from the two areas $A$ and $a$, and the (given?) density. Also, mass equations must be multiplied by a thickness, $t$ (maybe also given?) to get a volume.

The final answer is then:

$$
I_{0} = \frac{1}{2}MR^{2} -  \frac{1}{2}mr^{2} - md^{2}
$$

To get your book's final answer as requested in the comments below, note that as I was discussing above, the masses come from the volume and the density:

$$
M = \rho\pi R^{2}t
$$

$$
m = \rho\pi r^{2}t
$$

So that it should be clear that

$$
m = \frac{r^{2}}{R^{2}}M
$$

Therefore, substituting out $m$ for this:

$$
I_{0} = \frac{1}{2}MR^{2} - \frac{r^{2}}{R^{2}}M(\frac{1}{2}r^{2}+d^{2})
$$

Comment: Why not use the parallel axis theorem?

Comment: I am, I updated it with the final answer.

Comment: can you explain why the books final answer is $$\frac{1}{2}MR^2-(\frac{r^2M}{R^2})(\frac{1}{2}r^2+d^2)$$

Comment: OK sure, just a minute.

Comment: I already fix it

Comment: the book final answer has been hunting me for days

Comment: It is up. This is the question you should have asked above.

Comment: yea I thought that maybe there is another way of finding the moment of inertia of the hole

Comment: You can always do it from the integral definition, but your answer was not wrong, you just needed to put it into the book's form.

Comment: thank you sir..

Answer (score 1):

Considering a constant thickness $t$, the total mass of the disk is found from the total disk area, minus the cutout.

$$ m = \rho \left(t \pi R^2 - t \pi r^2 \right) \tag{1} $$

This is used to find the density of the solid $\rho$ in terms of the mass and the geometry. It will be used later for the mass moment of inertia calculations.

Now for **solid** disk of radius $R$ and density $\rho$ the MMOI about its center is $$I = \rho \int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^R  t\, r^2 \,r{\rm d}r = \tfrac{1}{2} \pi\, \rho\, t R^4 \tag{2}$$

For your problem specifically, you add the MMOI of the whole disk, but subtract the MMOI of the cutout and also subtract the parallel axis theorem contribution also. This requires the "mass" of the hole which is $\rho\, t\,\pi r^2$

$$ I = \underbrace{\tfrac{1}{2} \pi\, \rho\, t R^4}_\text{MMOI of disk } - \left(  \underbrace{\tfrac{1}{2} \pi\, \rho\, t r^4}_\text{MMOI of cutout} + \underbrace{(\rho t \pi r^2) d^2}_\text{Parallel axis}  \right) \tag{3}$$

$$ I = \tfrac{1}{2} \rho \pi t \left( R^4 -2 d^2 r^2 -r^4\right)$$

and using the density from (1) the above is

$$ \boxed{I = m\; \frac{R^4 - r^2 ( 2 d^2 +r^2)}{2(R^2-r^2)} } \tag{4} $$

We can check if the above makes sense. The two edge cases are: a) when $r=0$ then $I = \tfrac{m}{2} R^2$ which matches the MMOI value for a solid disk, b) when $d=0$ then $I=\tfrac{m}{2} ( R^2+r^2)$ which matches the MMOI value for a hollow tube.